# How to add icon to .dll files in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

How to add icon to .dll files in asp.net ? i making a custom control ie.dll file and i want to set an icon to it and use as a control in toolbox .

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [Resources.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

You can add resources to a project by right-clicking the **Properties** node under your project in Solution Explorer, clicking **Open**, and then clicking the **Add Resource** button on the Resources page in Project Designer.